# How to paste on separate line in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

In Sublime Text 3 and Resharper, when you paste(Ctrl+V) a copied line(Ctrl+C) on the caret location, it pastes the content on a new line above the line with the caret and adds a carriage return at the end.

For example, if I copy the entire line `Bar bar = new Bar();` and try to paste on the line `bar.getDrinks();`, I get the following output:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.getDrinks();
```

But in Android Studio the same operation results in the following:

```
bar.getDrinks(); Bar bar = new Bar();
```

provided the caret was after the semicolon in `bar.getDrinks();` code.

Does anyone know how to fix this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions I could find were to either:

1. (2 key press combinations) Go to the beginning of the current line, and paste the line copied, or
2. (4 key press combinations) Go to the line above -> Press Enter -> Paste the line copied -> Delete the line below the line copied.

I prefer to use the 1st method.